# Polymer: write demo and tests for a component that reacts to server response

Tags: javascript, validation, testing, polymer, polymer-1.0

I wrote an element that is meant as a container of , and that sets fields as invalid depending on the server response.

I would love to write demo and tests for this component. However, both demo and tests require the component to receive a response from a server (the form gets submitted, and fields are set accordingly).

Is there a way to write something like this in Polymer?

Comment: For tests using `WCT` you can look into [sinon](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/tests#ajax) or [stubs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/tests#create-stub-methods). And for how demo how about json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple and straightforward: use [SinonJs](http://sinonjs.org/). Specifically, use the [fakeServer feature](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) which rewrites the Ajax call in the browser so that you application actually "thinks" it's talking to a server. Easy.

I am using it myself in [hot-form-validator](https://github.com/mercmobily/hot-form-validator).